# How to copy all files from 'grep -L "hello" *' to a directory?

Tags: linux, grep

I do not see how to copy the files filtered by

```
grep -L "hello" *
```

to a folder. Probably there is an elegant way to pipeline this with `cp`?

Comment: cp \`grep -L [...]\` destinationDir. that or xargs.

Comment: how to use xargs? I also tried with -exec but cannot get right the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
grep -L "hello" * | xargs -I '{}' mv  '{}' /newDirectory
```

Comment: And as usual, this doesn't support file names with newlines, with the added bonus of failing with single quotes.

Comment: Version with fixes to handle newlines and single quotes: `grep -LZ "hello" * | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} /newDirectory`